# NSTextView line height changes when using CJK characters

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, cjk

I use `NSTextView` to render `NSAttributedString`s that may contain non-Latin characters, and it seems that lines containing any CJK character are *always* 6 pixels taller than lines without those. Even setting the `NSParagraphStyle`'s `minimumLineHeight` property to a much higher value (e.g. 32 pixels, when using the standard system font size) retains this problem (Lines with CJK characters a rendered as 38 pixels).

Moreover, `NSAttributedString`'s `boundingRectWithSize` seems to report the wrong ("correct") size (without the extra 6 pixels).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `layoutManager.usesFontLeading` to `NO` solved this problem.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to accept your own answer. Please, do this. It also help others a lot - they will see it as answered - less people will click on it - time saver - they can answer another questions.